# how to select automatically left side link, when I scroll the html page up and down of right side content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a page, that body contain two part left and right. left contain some anchor tag whose content are contain right. as like [enter link description here](http://journals.plos.org/plosntds/article?id=10.1371/journal.pntd.0000981)

Now, I want to scroll page and select automatically left anchor according to right side content.

Please help me any one.....

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to make an attempt.  SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: use position check for html.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=scroll+html+page+using+javascript&*

Comment: its closed. thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link https://davist11.github.io/jQuery-One-Page-Nav/filter.html
check html, css and jquery by view source.